# Basic HTTP authentication with Postman App

Tags: spring-security, postman, basic-authentication

I cannot understand one particular thing.
I am using `http-basic` authentication on my sever.

My code for that is:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/user/save")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/user/**")
                    .hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                    .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
```

And my request mapping for `/user` is:

```
@GetMapping
public Principal user(Principal user){
    return user;
}
```

When I query the endpoint `/user` with the username and password in the **postman app**, I get the desired authenticated result.

However, when I update the headers with an intentional wrong password, I **still** get the authenticated result. I cannot understand why this is so.

Also, the `POST` request on the endpoint `/logout` fails with:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-07-30T07:42:48.172+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/logout"
}
```

I cannot understand. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that looks helpful but how can I configure it to check the password too? OR
How can the logout functionality invalidate the session? The POST on the logout gives a `FORBIDDEN` response, and I don't get why.

Comment: *how can I configure it to check the password too?* As mentioned in a commentin the other question, you could disable HTTP session.

Comment: Okay I added a new question, it's here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590877/logout-not-working-in-basic-auth-in-spring-security